# Need help regarding URL redirect

Tags: php, html, redirect

I have 3 URLs

- Mainurl.com
- 2nndurl.com
- 3rdurl.com

I want to redirect path 3rdurl.com/post to 2ndurl.com/post

But if anyone opens 3rdurl.com it’s redirected to mainurl.com

Comment: Without telling how your done your redirect it's pretty difficult for anyone to know what's wrong

Comment: and what did you do so far? please share with us your code snippets or any useful information to help others answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

in 3rdurl.com insert index.php like this:

```
<?PHP
header("Location: https://Mainurl.com");
exit();
?>
```

in 3rdurl.com/post folder insert index.php like this:

```
<?PHP
header("Location: https://2ndurl.com/post");
exit();
?>
```